# Grab data from Twitter and parse

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to:

Grab multiple tweets, find urls inside the tweets, grab the urls I found and save each "url data" to different txt file.

So far I managed to write these parts and I am stuck, can someone please help me?

Grab tweets:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import sys
import re

def process_or_store(tweet):
    print(json.dumps(tweet))

consumer_key = '***************************'
consumer_secret = '******************************'
access_token = '*******************************'
access_secret = '****************************'
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

f = open("C:\\Twitter\Twitts.txt",'w')
print >>f, 'twits'


for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(20):
    # Process a single status
    print(status.text)
    f.write(status.text+ '\n')


def extract_urls(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', f.read())
```

Data from URL:

```
import urllib2

url = 'https://***************'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open('C:\\Twitter\Data_from_urls\ + "url"', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.read())
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what part of your code isn't working properly?  Are you getting something, but it isn't looking right, or are you not getting anything at all?  Also, remember to `.close()` your file after you `.write` the data into it.

Comment: i do not know how to write the part that take the urls (only the urls) from the txt and grap all the urls( multi thread or one by one ).

Comment: Well, it looks like your regex is mostly working, based on a few quick tests.  Your `extract_urls()` function should return a group of regex objects that you can iterate through.  You'll need another function that calls `extract_urls()`, and uses the result in a loop, inside which you can save the URL data to a file.